# Django Keep different session in different tabs

Tags: python, django, session, dajaxice

I have django app (1.6) where I want to be able open two tabs with different sessions.
But now when I open first tab with form to write a post, and on second tab I switch to different tab I also have the same session in this tab, because I refresh session.

Is the way to separate sessions?

Thanks for any help.

JS part of my code:

```
setInterval(function () {
  Dajaxice.calendars.get_calendar_name(function(data){
        $('#calendars_name').html(data.calendar);
    });
}, 10000);
```

Python part of my code:

```
@dajaxice_register
def get_calendar_name(request):
    c = request.session["current_calendar"].name
    return simplejson.dumps({'calendar': c})
```

Comment: The browser keeps sessions across those tabs. You don't have control of it.

Comment: or you can use 2 different name for the session variable to use

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the calendar objects in session, store them in the database. Your ajax can them request the calendar from Django by simply passing it the `id` of the calendar that you have open in that tab.